# What does cast do exactly?

Tags: casting, type-conversion, union, d

I was playing with integer array hashing and the different ways to go from a representation to the other. I ended up with the following:

```
void main(string[] args) {
    import std.algorithm, std.array, std.conv, std.stdio, std.digest.md;

    union hashU {
        ubyte[] hashA;
        int[]   hashN;
    };

    hashU a;
    auto md5 = new MD5Digest();

    a.hashN = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

    /* Using an union, no actual data conversion */
    md5.put( a.hashA );
    auto hash = md5.finish();
    writeln(hash);
    // [253, 255, 63, 4, 193, 99, 182, 232, 28, 231, 57, 107, 18, 254, 75, 175]

    /* Using a cast... Doesn't match any of the other representations */
    md5.put( cast(ubyte[])(a.hashN) );
    hash = md5.finish();
    writeln(hash);
    // [254, 5, 74, 210, 231, 185, 139, 238, 103, 63, 159, 242, 45, 80, 240, 12]

    /* Using .to! to convert from array to array */
    md5.put( a.hashN.to!(ubyte[]) );
    hash = md5.finish();
    writeln(hash);
    // [124, 253, 208, 120, 137, 179, 41, 93, 106, 85, 9, 20, 171, 53, 224, 104]

    /* This matches the previous transformation */
    md5.put( a.hashN.map!(x => x.to!ubyte).array );
    hash = md5.finish();
    writeln(hash);
    // [124, 253, 208, 120, 137, 179, 41, 93, 106, 85, 9, 20, 171, 53, 224, 104]
}
```

My question is the following: what does the cast do? I'd have expected it to do either the same as .to! or the union trick, but it doesn't seem so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, cast simply tells the compiler to start talking to the chunk of memory that you've cast as the type you've cast it to.

The last two options in your example actually convert the numbers to the new type, and so do some *actual* work. Which is why they end up being the same values.

The issue in your first two examples is that the int[] is larger in memory than the ubyte[]. (4 bytes per element vs 1 byte per element)

I've edited your first two methods:

```
    /* Using an union, no actual data conversion */
md5.put( a.hashA );
auto hash = md5.finish();
writefln("Hash of: %s -> %s", a.hashA, hash);
// Hash of: [1, 0, 0, 0, 2] -> [253, 255, 63, 4, 193, 99, 182, 232, 28, 231, 57, 107, 18, 254, 75, 175] 
// notice 5 bytes in first array

/* Using a cast... Doesn't match any of the other representations */
md5.put( cast(ubyte[])(a.hashN) );
hash = md5.finish();
writefln("Hash of: %s -> %s", cast(ubyte[])(a.hashN), hash);
// Hash of: [1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0] -> [254, 5, 74, 210, 231, 185, 139, 238, 103, 63, 159, 242, 45, 80, 240, 12] 
// notice 20 bytes (4 x 5 bytes) in first array
```

So in the first, you're reading the length of ubyte[]'s bytes. In the second your casting the length of int[]'s length to ubyte[].

Edit: Prob wasn't clear. A union is pretty dumb, it simply stores all the values in the same memory. When you go to read any of them out, it will only read X bits of that memory, depending on the length of the type you're reading.

So because you're reading the int[] THEN casting it, it reads all 20 of the bytes and casts them to a ubyte[]. Which is of course different than just reading the 5 bytes of the ubyte[] variable.

I think I made sense there :)

Answer (score 4):

I think Colin Grogan has it right, but his wording is a little confusing.

Using the union, the array is simply reinterpreted, no calculation/computation happens at all. The pointer and length of the `int[]` are reinterpreted to refer to `ubyte` elements. Before: 5 ints, after: 5 ubytes.

The cast is a little smarter than that: It adjusts the length of the array so that it refers to the same memory as before. Before: 5 ints, after: 20 ubytes (5*`int.sizeof`/`ubyte.sizeof` = 5*4/1 = 20).

Both the union and the cast reinterpret the bytes of the ints as ubytes. That is, an int value 1 will result in 4 ubytes: 0,0,0,1, or 1,0,0,0 depending on endianess.

The `to` variants convert every single element to the new element type. Before: 5 ints, after: 5 ubytes with the same values as the ints. If one of the ints couldn't be converted to a ubyte, `to` would throw an exception.

Printing the elements after the various conversions might help clarifying what happens where:

```
void main()
{
    import std.algorithm, std.array, std.conv, std.stdio;

    union hashU
    {
        ubyte[] hashA;
        int[]   hashN;
    }
    hashU a;
    a.hashN = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

    writeln( a.hashA ); /* union -> [1, 0, 0, 0, 2] (depends on endianess) */

    writeln( cast(ubyte[])(a.hashN) );
        /* cast -> [1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0]
        (depends on endianess) */

    writeln( a.hashN.to!(ubyte[]) ); /* `to` -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`cast` is a D operator used when developer needs to perform an explicit type conversion.